# BioGPT causal language model with unexpected error

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I am trying to use a Causal Language Model from BioGPT. However, I got a strange error.

Here are my steps:

First, I installed `transformers` and `sacremoses`:

```
!pip install transformers sacremoses -q
```

Then I executed the following code:

```
input_sequence = "Hello, I'm a language model,"

inputs = torch.as_tensor(tokenizer.encode(input_sequence)).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
past_key_values = None

count = 0
complete_token = []
with torch.no_grad():
    while count<10:
        count += 1
        print("Iteration no.: " + str(count))
        if count > 1:
            inputs = input_token

        model_out = model(input_ids=inputs.to(device), past_key_values=past_key_values)
        logits = model_out.logits[:, -1, :]
        past_key_values = model_out.past_key_values

        topk_values, topk_indices = torch.topk(logits, 5)

        log_probs = F.softmax(topk_values, dim=-1)
        inputs_in_topk = torch.multinomial(log_probs, num_samples=1, replacement=True)
        input_token = torch.gather(topk_indices, 1, inputs_in_topk)
        complete_token.append(input_token)
```

And here is the error I got:

```
Iteration no.: 1
Iteration no.: 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_18990/2689790310.py in <cell line: 8>()
     13             inputs = input_token
     14 
---> 15         model_out = model(input_ids=inputs.to(device), past_key_values=past_key_values)
     16         logits = model_out.logits[:, -1, :]
     17         past_key_values = model_out.past_key_values

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1192         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/biogpt/modeling_biogpt.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, head_mask, inputs_embeds, past_key_values, labels, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    677         return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict
    678 
--> 679         outputs = self.biogpt(
    680             input_ids,
    681             attention_mask=attention_mask,

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1192         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/biogpt/modeling_biogpt.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, head_mask, inputs_embeds, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    589                 )
    590             else:
--> 591                 layer_outputs = decoder_layer(
    592                     hidden_states,
    593                     attention_mask=attention_mask,

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1192         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/biogpt/modeling_biogpt.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, layer_head_mask, past_key_value, output_attentions, use_cache)
    313         self_attn_past_key_value = past_key_value[:2] if past_key_value is not None else None
    314         # add present self-attn cache to positions 1,2 of present_key_value tuple
--> 315         hidden_states, self_attn_weights, present_key_value = self.self_attn(
    316             hidden_states=hidden_states,
    317             past_key_value=self_attn_past_key_value,

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1192         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/biogpt/modeling_biogpt.py in forward(self, hidden_states, key_value_states, past_key_value, attention_mask, layer_head_mask, output_attentions)
    211         if attention_mask is not None:
    212             if attention_mask.size() != (bsz, 1, tgt_len, src_len):
--> 213                 raise ValueError(
    214                     f"Attention mask should be of size {(bsz, 1, tgt_len, src_len)}, but is {attention_mask.size()}"
    215                 )

ValueError: Attention mask should be of size (1, 1, 0, 12), but is torch.Size([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

So apparently, everything went fine in the first execution, but the in the second model call this error came up.

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Which model are you using? (Link to the model link/card on huggingface.co) What's your `transformers` version?

Answer (score 2):

The canonical usage of `BioGPT` https://huggingface.co/microsoft/biogpt as documented is as such:

```
from transformers import pipeline, set_seed
from transformers import BioGptTokenizer, BioGptForCausalLM
model = BioGptForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")
tokenizer = BioGptTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")

generator = pipeline('text-generation', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
set_seed(42)

generator("COVID-19 is", max_length=20, num_return_sequences=5, do_sample=True)
```

[out]:

```
[{'generated_text': 'COVID-19 is a disease that spreads worldwide and is currently found in a growing proportion of the population'},
 {'generated_text': 'COVID-19 is one of the largest viral epidemics in the world.'},
 {'generated_text': 'COVID-19 is a common condition affecting an estimated 1.1 million people in the United States alone.'},
 {'generated_text': 'COVID-19 is a pandemic, the incidence has been increased in a manner similar to that in other'},
 {'generated_text': 'COVID-19 is transmitted via droplets, air-borne, or airborne transmission.'}]
```

## Lets break it down

But if you need to use the custom way of generation as per your question, we'll have to go through each step to better understand what you're trying to do.

### The tokenizer

```
import torch
from transformers import BioGptTokenizer, BioGptForCausalLM

input_sequence = "Hello, I'm a language model,"

tokenizer = BioGptTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")
inputs = torch.as_tensor(tokenizer.encode(input_sequence)).unsqueeze(0).to('cpu')
inputs
```

[out]:

```
tensor([[   2,  313, 3666,  399,    7,  174, 4617,  659,   14, 2545,  144,    7]])
```

From the output we see that the goal is to get the vocab ids given the text inputs. In that case you can simplify the code to this:

```
from transformers import BioGptTokenizer, BioGptForCausalLM

tokenizer = BioGptTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")


input_sequence = "Hello, I'm a language model,"
encoded_input = tokenizer(input_sequence, return_tensors='pt')
encoded_input
```

[out]:

```
{'input_ids': tensor([[   2,  313, 3666,  399,    7,  174, 4617,  659,   14, 2545,  144,    7]]), 'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])}
```

#### The loop

Lets try to break the down while-loop with some comments.

```
# Keep track of the no. of times we want to iterate.
count = 0

# Keep track of generated tokens.
complete_token = []

# Okay, this to to say that we want model in eval() model.
with torch.no_grad():
    # Looping through 10 times.
    while count<10:
        count += 1 
        print("Iteration no.: " + str(count))
        if count > 1: # If it's the 2nd loop or after use the input_token
            inputs = input_token
        ...
```

In that case, you can actually simplify the while loop with a more intuitive for loop,

```
# Keep track of generated tokens.
complete_token = []

# This way you don't have to check if the loop is the 2nd round or after.
input_token = input

with torch.no_grad():
    for count in range(10): # Much simpler than while and if-checks.
        print("Iteration no.: " + str(count))
        ...
```

#### The forward pass

Similarly lets comment the lines to understand what you're trying to achieve

```
        # Put the input through the models' forward pass.
        model_out = model(input_ids=inputs.to(device), past_key_values=past_key_values)

        # Get the logits of the outputs.
        logits = model_out.logits[:, -1, :]

        # We actually don't have to set this here 
        # and it's better to be put at the end of the loop.
        past_key_values = model_out.past_key_values

        # Take the top-5 outputs.
        topk_values, topk_indices = torch.topk(logits, 5)

        # Do a softmax on the top-5 candidates.
        log_probs = F.softmax(topk_values, dim=-1)

        # Put the log probs outputs through a 
        # multinomial distribution to pick out sample generation.
        inputs_in_topk = torch.multinomial(log_probs, num_samples=1, replacement=True)

        # Collect the tokens of the generated sample
        input_token = torch.gather(topk_indices, 1, inputs_in_topk)
        complete_token.append(input_token)
```

Lets do a single forward pass first:

```
from transformers import BioGptTokenizer, BioGptForCausalLM

tokenizer = BioGptTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")


input_sequence = "Hello, I'm a language model,"
encoded_input = tokenizer(input_sequence, return_tensors='pt')

past_key_values = None
model_out = model(encoded_input["input_ids"], past_key_values=past_key_values)

model_out
```

[out]:

```
 [[-5.1395e-02,  8.2569e-02,  4.4981e-02,  ..., -3.1730e-02,
           -1.3441e-01,  7.4366e-02],
          [-4.5237e-01, -8.1031e-01, -4.9237e-01,  ..., -9.4491e-02,
            1.1978e+00, -9.9674e-01],
          [ 4.8585e-01,  2.1312e+00,  1.9036e+00,  ...,  1.6909e+00,
            3.3308e-01, -1.7083e-01],
          ...,
          [ 1.2736e-01,  3.4345e-01, -4.6991e-01,  ...,  4.0779e-02,
           -5.1480e-01,  4.2456e-01]]]], grad_fn=<CloneBackward0>))), hidden_states=None, attentions=None, cross_attentions=None)
```

**It works! And this should resolve your issue in the original question with the error**:

> ValueError: Attention mask should be of size (1, 1, 0, 12), but is torch.Size([1, 1, 1, 1])

For the rest of the generation code, I'll suggest following how https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.28.1/src/transformers/generation/utils.py#L1911 if you're trying to roll your own generate function.

---

If you want to **generate 10 tokens with greedy decoding**, try this:

```
from torch.functional import F
from transformers import BioGptTokenizer, BioGptForCausalLM

tokenizer = BioGptTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")


input_sequence = "Hello, I'm a language model,"
encoded_input = tokenizer(input_sequence, return_tensors='pt')

# If you want to generate 10 more tokens.
model.generate(**encoded_input, max_new_tokens=10)
```

[out]:

```
tensor([[   2,  313, 3666,  399,    7,  174, 4617,  659,   14, 2545,  144,    7,
            8,  174, 4617,  659,   14, 2545,  144,    4,    2]])
```

---

If you want to **generate 10 tokens sampling from the distribution**, try this:

```
from torch.functional import F
from transformers import BioGptTokenizer, BioGptForCausalLM

tokenizer = BioGptTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")


input_sequence = "Hello, I'm a language model,"
encoded_input = tokenizer(input_sequence, return_tensors='pt')

# If you want to generate 10 more tokens.
model.sample(**encoded_input, max_new_tokens=10)
```

[out]:

```
tensor([[    2,   313,  3666,   399,     7,   174,  4617,   659,    14,  2545,
           144,     7,   112,  3903,  7748, 22089, 30634,  9774,     6,  1207,
            23, 14906,   387,     6,  6841,  3656,   442,     7,    46,    17,
           451,    10,    91,   113,     5,   488,     4,     2]])
```

And for the readers curious about what the model actually generates:

```
from torch.functional import F
from transformers import BioGptTokenizer, BioGptForCausalLM

tokenizer = BioGptTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")


input_sequence = "Hello, I'm a language model,"
encoded_input = tokenizer(input_sequence, return_tensors='pt')

# If you want to generate 10 more tokens.
tokens_ids = model.sample(**encoded_input, max_new_tokens=10)

tokenizer.decode(tokens_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
```

[out]:

```
Hello, I'm a language model, unless it is possible that we can terate particular population models with complex psychological and neural mechanisms.
```

Comment: Hi @alvas, many thanks for your input. For a single forward pass it works. However, this iterated approach is more what I need in order to have a look at the data in between. And for most models (like the OPT models at hugging face) a basically identical approach just works fine. Hence, I really would benefit from entering everything with this loop.

Comment: Is the goal to just keep generating and continue the sentence? If so, try extending the max_new_tokens with `model.sample(...)`

Comment: Many thanks again, @alvas. My thoughts are more along the following lines: I have a bunch inputs as batch. Then I make a prediction and store the the probabilities, then  I select one word for each line in the batch and proceed, therefore the `past_key_values`. Do you have a better idea how to make that happen?

Comment: Do you think we can do something along the lines I was outlining above?